# Best way to store password into sql

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, passwords

in my current C# windows application password has been stored in plain text which is obviously not good. so i just want to know what is the best way to encrypt the password and stored into SQL Server. I have read that using hash+salt is better. but i feel "EncryptByPassPhrase","DecryptByPassPhrase" new feature in sql 2005 is better to use because you are handling everything from SQL Server itself and i suppose it uses triple DES.  can somebody suggest is it good to use it ?

Comment: thnks a lot for ur replies. i think using sha1 or sha256 with salt shud be good. only drwabck is tht i cannot decrpyt it. but still it makes sense. but  i also came to know abt BCRYPT which looks to me good ,but for my proj it wud be enough to use SHA itself. if anybody wants to know abt bcrypt then chk ths link-
http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx

Answer (score 5):

Do you need to have access to the original password, or are you just going to try and compare an entered password against one in the database?

If you need access to the original password, then you are going to have to use an encryption algorithm instead of a hash algorithm.

If all you're doing is storing a password in the database so that you can check it later against a known input value, then a hash with a salt will work.

Remember that when the client is sending the credentials across to be validated, that you don't want to be sending the password in clear text!

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph. How do you send the password? Do you hash it client side and send the hash? If so, wouldn't the client be able to see the algorithm used?

Comment: @miparnisari It doesn't matter if they know what the hashing algorithm is that is used - the point of a one-way hash is that given the output, it is very difficult to find the input.  The help fight against [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) you should use a salt (bonus points: use a different salt per user) to make it so that if a bad actor ends up with a full copy of your password hashes, they would have to compute a bunch of rainbow tables to brute force out all of your passwords.

Answer (score 3):

A hash & salt is the way to go, because its impossible to retrieve the original password from it. If you encrypt then decrypt the password, the plaintext password is retrievable so its not the best.

Answer (score 2):

I agree it makes sense to have the encryption all in 1 place. However if you separate the key from the data (key in the c# code, data in the db), that will increase security.  Also, Sql Server uses a master key when encrypting, which means if you need to restore the data to a new server, you will have trouble restoring the data.

This all comes down to key management and how you want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As with most questions the best answer depends on the context of your situation.  There is no good solution.

Some options:

1. Leave the password in plain text or reversably encrypt.  Use SQLServer facilities to encrypt important fields at the RDBMS level or use similiar encryption functions and hope that MS has implemented reasonable key management and the keys are reasonably secure for your purposes. In practice all encryption does is collapse storage of a whole lot of little secrets into storage of one big secret.. It might make the problem more managable but the problem itself never goes away.
2. Irreversably "Encrypt" the password using a hashing algorithm or some form of crypt().  Depending on the attack vectors available this method may not provide much in the way of actual improvment of security over plaintext storage.

. Use of hashed passwords limits your options in terms of selection of a secure authentication algorithm. With this approach you will likely end up sending plain texts or other material that is no better over a transport (regardless of if unbound encryption is used or not) this can be a substantial risk from a trust POV.

. Succeptable to offline dictionary attack if hashes are stolen recovery of some portion of passwords should be outright assumed if they have any value to an attacker.

. In some cases knowledge of the password hash can be just as bad as knowing the password in terms of system access.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that you will never use a hashed scheme to authenticate (like HTTP Digest Auth), hashed password is more secure. To avoid rainbow table attack, please use a nonce (or salt). I would use HMAC-SHA1 and use the nonce as the key. They key must be stored with the password.

Otherwise, you will have to store encrypted password because hashed password can't work with authentication involving hashes. For encryption, I have following suggestions,

1. Don't store the key in DB, don't hardcode it either. Store it some other secure place, like using DPAPI on Windows.
2. Make sure you have a key version so you can rotate the key to comply with certain standards.
3. I am not familiar with the encryption in SQLServer. Make sure it has a random Initial Vector. You can check this by encrypting same password twice, it should yield different ciphertext. If no random IV, don't use it, just encrypt it in your application.